# Combining two given sequences into a new increasing sequence

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I am doing the following problem:

> Giving the sequence `a` consisting of `n` integer numbers and the sequence `b` consisting of `m` integer numbers, two sequences are arranged in increasing order. Combining two above sequences into a new sequence `c` such that `c` is also an increasing sequence. Printing `c`.

Input:

```
3
1 3 4
4     
1 2 3 5
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

My idea is first combining two sequences into sequence `c`, then sorting sequence `c` in increasing order. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //Inputting sequence a and b
    int n, m;
    int a[1001], b[1001];

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }

    //Combine two sequence into c
    int c[1001];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        c[i + n] = b[i];
    }

    //Arrange sequence c in increasing order
    int mid;
    for (int i = 0; i < (n + m - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n + m); j++) {
            if (c[i] > c[j]) {
                mid = c[i];
                c[i] = c[j];
                c[j] = mid;
            }
        }
    }

    //Printing c
    for (int i = 0; i < (n + m); i++) {
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I test with the test case `[1,2,4],[1,2,5]`, the result is `1 4 2 2 1 5`. Can anyone point out the error in my code? I truly appreciate that.

Comment: If you know sequence a and b are already sorted, why not use that fact while adding the entries to c?

Comment: The instructions are asking you to *merge two sorted sequences*. Those last four words in a search box on this site are probably going to tell you exactly how to do it, and far more efficiently than than O(N^2) algorithm you're currently using. That both initial sequence are already sorted is a *hugely* important attribute.

Comment: Consider adding some input validation since you allocate predefined amount of memory for both sets `a` and `b` and the value obtained via input might be greater. Also array `c`  should be declared at least the size equal to the size of arrays `a` and `b` combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong to search for the minimum value in the range of `1` to `n+m-1` regardless of the value `i`. This may move the minimum value to the latter part of the array.

The line

```
        for (int j = 1; j < (n+m); j++)
```

should be

```
        for (int j = i + 1; j < (n+m); j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge 2 sorted arrays, you can write 3 loops as in the classic implementation of mergesort:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //Inputting sequence a and b
    int a[1000], b[1000], c[2000];
    int n, m, i, j, k;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0 || n > 1000)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    if (scanf("%d", &m) != 1 || m <= 0 || m > 1000)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &b[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    //Combine both sequences into c

    i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < n && j < m) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j])
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            c[k++] = b[j++];
    }
    while (i < n) {
        c[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j < m) {
        c[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    //Printing c
    for (i = 0; i < n + m; i++) {
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```